# git-tfs: Preview changes

Tags: git-tfs

Can I preview the changes that will be checked-in to TFS without using `git tfs checkintool`?

I'd prefer a better UI like GitGui and I'd prefer not to risk accidentally clicking Ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually work with git and making feature branch using just pure git tools (and there you can use whatever you like - GitExtensions, Git Source Control Provider for VS, TortoiseGit, SmartGit etc). When I have my branch ready to be pushed to TFS - I ensure that my branch is rebased onto latest TFS commit and run `git tfs rcheckin`.

Basically what is going to be in TFS after any sort of git-tfs checkin is the same you have in your local git commit(s).

Comment: After the rebase is there a way to see what the changes are? Perhaps a git way to compare the branch vs master?

Comment: You can run `git log` or browse history with any tool you like and check changes when you need it. It will go to TFS sequentially one-by-one.
If you use TortoiseGit, for example, you can run `Show log...` command, select two commits you want to compare and select `Compare revisions` from context menu. Though, it had nothing to do with git-tfs, it is pure git experience.